# How the command dist(x,method="binary") calculates the distance matrix?

Tags: r, distance

I have a been trying to figure that out but without much success. I am working with a table with binary data (0s and 1s). I managed to estimate a distance matrix from my data using the **R** function `dist(x,method="binary")`, but I am not quite sure how exactly this function estimates the distance matrix. Is it using the Jaccard coefficient J=(M11)/(M10+M01+M11)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is easily found in the help page `?dist`:

> This function computes and returns the distance matrix computed by using the specified distance measure to compute the distances between the rows of a data matrix.
>
> [...]
>
> binary: (aka asymmetric binary): The vectors are regarded as binary
> bits, so non-zero elements are ‘on’ and zero elements are ‘off’. The
> distance is the proportion of bits in which only one is on amongst
> those in which at least one is on.

This is equivalent to the [Jaccard distance as described in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index):

> An alternate interpretation of the Jaccard distance is as the ratio of the size of the symmetric difference to the union.

In your notation, it is 1 - J = (M01 + M10)/(M01 + M10 + M11).

Comment: But the proportion of bits in which only one is on amongst those in which at least one is on is not the same as the ratio of the symmetric diffetrence to the union, is it? The latter has as as denominator the size of the full set, while the former has as denominator the size of the set of bits in which not both are "off"?